# Trig limit of $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin{6x}}{\sin{2x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin{6x}}{\sin{2x}}$$

I have no idea at all on how to proceed. I am guessing there is some trig rule about manipulating these terms in some way but I can not find it in my notes.

I tried to make $\tan$ into $\dfrac\sin\cos$

$$\frac{\sin6x}{\cos6x} \times \frac{1}{\sin2x}$$

But this doesn't get me anywhere as far as I can tell.

Comment: Show us your work!

Comment: I don't really have any.

Comment: $$\frac{\sin\,3x}{\sin\,x}=2\cos\,2x+1$$ might be useful...

Comment: Are there any nice equivalences you could use?

Comment: Cancel the sines and $x$'s to get 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin{6x}}{\sin{2x}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{6}{2}=3.
$$

Comment: @Cam: sounds awfully like a "Lucky Larry"... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{\sin{6x}}{\sin{2x}}=\frac{\frac{\sin{6x}}{x}}{\frac{\sin{2x}}{x}}$$

And you returning to your previous problem.

Comment: Maybe you should divide by $6x,2x$ to help the PO understand this hint

Comment: I have no idea why but I did not realize that you could do that to the problem.

Comment: @jordan: The only way to solve such these limits is what Salech pointed above. Use the HINT and note that When $x$ tents to $0$, it will be Ok, if you write your fraction as above. No more tricks needed.

Comment: Well, maybe another "trick": ${\sin 6x\over x}= 6\cdot{\sin 6x\over 6x}$ and  ${\sin 2x\over x}=2\cdot{\sin 2x\over 2x}$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Nice variant

Comment: I prefer this method (+1) over the others because it uses the more primary and useful limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$. This is a very useful thing to learn and remember. It tells you that for small enough x, sin(x) can be simply be approximated by x.

Answer (score 7):

Three different proofs:

By L'Hôpital:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{\sin(2x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{6\cos(6x)}{2\cos(2x)}=\frac 62=3$$

By trigonometric identity:
We have $\sin(3x)=\sin(x)(4\cos^2(x)-1)$ and therefore
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{\sin(2x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(2x)(4\cos^2(2x)-1)}{\sin(2x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}(4\cos^2(2x)-1)=4-1=3$$

If you now $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{\sin(2x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}3\frac{\frac{\sin(6x)}{6x}}{\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}}=3\frac11=3$$

Comment: Am I suppose to have that triple angle identity memorized?

Comment: Nah, obviously not ;) But it's obtained by applying the usual identities a couple of times. I always have to look them up myself. You just need to know that you can reduce the factor somehow.

Comment: Somehow I can't help but feel that using l'Hôpital here is like cutting toothpicks with a chainsaw...

Answer (score 4):

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{\sin(2x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(6x)\cdot(6x/6x)}{\sin(2x)\cdot(2x/2x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{6x}{2x}\frac{\frac{\sin(6x)}{6x}}{\frac{\cos(2x)}{2x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{6x}{2x}\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{6x}}{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}}=\frac{6}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1}=3.$

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

$$\sin6x=2(\sin 3x \cos3x)$$

$$\sin2x=2 \sin x \cos x $$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(\cos x) = 1$$

You will have $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin3x}{\sin x}$ so using @J.M. $\lim_{x\to 0}(2\cos2x + 1) = 3$.

Comment: Even though in this case the limit result is not hard to get by playing with trigonometric identities, exploiting knowledge about $\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\sin u}{u}$ seems more appropriate, since this is a calculus course. Moreover, the idea deals with equal ease with $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\sqrt{2} x)}{\sin x}$.

Comment: No problem, this site uses some form of latex for displaying equations, you have to surround the mathematics with \$ for an inline piece of mathematics and \$\$ for a "displayed" piece. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX might be a good place to find out more.

Answer (score 2):

I also feel compelled to mention that, in general,

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(Ax)}{\sin(Bx)}=\frac{A}{B}$$

which was proved for your case by others above.

Answer (score 0):

There are way too many ways to do this , this is just meant to be an addition to the many approaches that can be used;

If $\lambda(x)$ is an infinitesimal as $x \to 0$ we've
$$\sin(\lambda(x)) \sim \lambda(x)$$

Therefore for the present case the limit is just $\frac{6}{2}=3$